# Refactor componentWillReceiveProps to Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik Effect library to control my onChange effect. However the Formik Effect Library is broken, so then I need to write my own Effect to trigger the Formik `onChange()` function. I wrote a `class` componentWillReceiveProps component for my `<Effect />`. However, all my components are functions components. I am requested to refactor my `class` component to function component. I am a still a beginner of React, so I am struggling how to refactor it.

This is my class `<Effect />` component

```
// TODO: refactor with HOOK!

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'formik';

class Effect extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { formik } = this.props;
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting } = formik;
    const {
      values: nextValues,
      touched: nextTouched,
      errors: nextErrors,
      isSubmitting: nextIsSubmitting
    } = nextProps.formik;
    if (nextProps.formik !== formik) {
      onChange(
        {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          isSubmitting
        },
        {
          values: nextValues,
          touched: nextTouched,
          errors: nextErrors,
          isSubmitting: nextIsSubmitting
        }
      );
    }
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

Effect.defaultProps = {
  formik: {
    errors: {},
    touched: {},
    values: {},
    isSubmitting: false
  },
  onChange: () => {}
};

Effect.propTypes = {
  formik: PropTypes.shape({
    errors: PropTypes.shape({}),
    touched: PropTypes.shape({}),
    values: PropTypes.shape({}),
    isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool
  }),
  onChange: PropTypes.func
};

export default connect(Effect);
```

Within my , I return

```
<Effect
 onChange={(currentFormikState, nextFormikState) => {
                    if (
                      currentFormikState &&
                      nextFormikState &&
                      currentFormikState.values.pdsaType !==
                        nextFormikState.values.pdsaType
                    ) {
                      resetForm(initialValues[nextFormikState.values.type]);
                      setType(nextFormikState.values.type);
                    }
                  }}
                />
```

The purpose of this Effect is to reset the initialValue when user select a different type of form because initialValue only render once. And the current Formik library doesn't support onChange() function.

The `currentFormikState` is the initialValue that Formik render, and the `nextFormikState` is the `type` value that user select.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *formik* but I guess from your code you can transform to function component like this

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Effect(props) {
  const { formik, onChange } = props;
  const { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting } = formik;
  const formVariableRef = useRef();
  const formFormikRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    formFormikRef.current = formik;
    formVariableRef.current = { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting };
    if (formik !== formFormikRef) {
      onChange(
        {
          value: formVariableRef.current.values,
          touched: formVariableRef.current.touched,
          errors: formVariableRef.current.errors,
          isSubmitting: formVariableRef.current.isSubmitting
        },
        { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting }
      );
    }
    return function() {
      formFormikRef.current = formik;
      formVariableRef.current = { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting };
    };
  }, [values, touched, errors, isSubmitting, formik]); //try add this
  return null
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Try this one in replace for your class form. The rest might not need to change.

***Updated*** Try adding the code above. I just add some dependencies to `useEffect`

Comment: this is what I tired to refactor at the beginning but it does not work. Once I replace the code, it shows `Create.js:154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: I figured out it is a typo problems, but it does not work :(